# Check one column cell to another entire column in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file which contain two columns 
first column with Part number and second one is Image Name (Multiple Image for each product and Image Name based on Part Number )

I want to check each Part number with entire second column of Image Name  each time as this is not sorted properly and store that image name for that perticuler part number in another csv  along with that part number.

Current CSV

```
PartNumber  Image Name
WP35001153  35001153R.jpg
WPW10135901 35001153R_Back.jpg
WPW10184873 W10135901R.jpg
WPW10200900 W10135901R_BACK.jpg
WPW10215493 W10137702R.jpg
WPW10249237 W10137702R_Back.jpg
WPW10258402 W10141364R.jpg
WPW10477076 W10477076R.jpg
WP8194064   W10477076R_Back.jpg
            W10479760R.jpg
```

As above csv Part one `WP35001153` have two images in on right side `35001153R.jpg` and `35001153R_Back.jpg`

Also Part number column and Image Column is not perticulary or properly assigned.

So I want to search Part Number with Image name entrie column and if it matches then store in `Image1` Column and  more than two times it should be store in next column `Image2` like below.

```
PartNumber  Image1          Image2
WP35001153  35001153R.jpg   35001153R_Back.jpg
WPW10135901 W10135901R.jpg  W10135901R_BACK.jpg
WPW10200900 W10200900.jpg
```

Please help to figure it out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seem you need to build a new array, using your first column (of csv), cleaned as a key and add to it all you find related too.

Exemple (not exact code)

```
$mynewarray = [];
foreach ($mycsv as $line) {
  $id = $line['PartNumber'];
  if ($id[2] == 'W') {
    it's a key, clean to obtain : 35001153
    mynewarray[$id] = ['pics'=>[ ... ]];
  } else {
    it's a pic, add the image name
    clean the id image name to obtain the key 35001153
    mynewarray[$id]['pics'][] = the pics;
  }
}
```

If i understand well your need, this is the idea can solve your problem in one loop with few id analyze.

:) enjoy